# MS SQL.Summation of various values across columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g

Table T1 has 3 columns as C1, C2 and C3 having values as R, G, B

```
C1  C2  C3
R   R   R
R   R   R
G   R   R
G   G   R
B   G   B
B   B   B
```

I want a new table in the below structure:

```
R   G   B
9   4   5
```

In the above table, the distinct values of the Table T1 has to be displayed as the column name and the total count of the R, G, B values from the whole table has to be displayed.

Comment: Your title says "MS SQL" which refers to "Microsoft SQL Server". However you tagged the question with `oracle11g` which is a completely different product. Which DBMS are you **really** using?

Comment: I want it in MS SQL and Oracle 11g both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `COUNT` aggregation function on each column with a `CASE` expression to filter by the correct character value:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/830e2/4)

**Oracle and/or MS SQL Server Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  C1 CHAR(1),
  C2 CHAR(1),
  C3 CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'R', 'R', 'R' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'R', 'R', 'R' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'G', 'R', 'R' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'G', 'G', 'R' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'B', 'G', 'B' );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( 'B', 'B', 'B' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT   COUNT( CASE C1 WHEN 'R' THEN 1 END )
       + COUNT( CASE C2 WHEN 'R' THEN 1 END )
       + COUNT( CASE C3 WHEN 'R' THEN 1 END ) AS R,
         COUNT( CASE C1 WHEN 'G' THEN 1 END )
       + COUNT( CASE C2 WHEN 'G' THEN 1 END )
       + COUNT( CASE C3 WHEN 'G' THEN 1 END ) AS G,
         COUNT( CASE C1 WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END )
       + COUNT( CASE C2 WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END )
       + COUNT( CASE C3 WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END ) AS B
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/830e2/4/0)**:

```
| R | G | B |
|---|---|---|
| 9 | 4 | 5 |
```

**Query 2** or you can use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT   COUNT( CASE value WHEN 'R' THEN 1 END ) AS R,
         COUNT( CASE value WHEN 'G' THEN 1 END ) AS G,
         COUNT( CASE value WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END ) AS B
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT ( value FOR id IN ( C1, C2, C3 ) ) AS u -- Do not need AS keyword in Oracle
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/830e2/4/1)**:

```
| R | G | B |
|---|---|---|
| 9 | 4 | 5 |
```